# Toolbar menu being cleared after being set (When activity is started)

Tags: java, android

Toolbar menu is inflated in fragment but then cleared later.

When activity is first created (or rotated) the toolbar menu is inflated properly in the fragment, but then gets cleared before it can be displayed.

I set the toolbar menu in my fragment's `onActivityCreated`, and it stays set through `onResume` in the activity. The next call I've found is in `onCreateOptionsMenu` in the activity, but at this point `toolbar.getMenu().size() = 0`

Somewhere between `onResume` and `onCreateOptionsMenu` the toolbar menu is getting reset.

Edit: 
I'm not sure what is necessary to reproduce it, but here is all(?) of the relevant code.
Activity:

```
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.main_fab);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer,toolbar,R.string.nav_drawer_open,R.string.nav_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            showFragment(ScheduleFragment.newInstance());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        CharSequence retainTitle = toolbar.getTitle();
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        toggle.syncState();
        toolbar.setTitle(retainTitle);
    }
```

Fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        toolbar = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getToolbar();
        setMenuAction(MENU_ACTION_DELETE);
    }
    protected void setMenuAction(int menuAction) {
        Log.d(logger, "setting the menu");
        switch(menuAction) {
            case MENU_ACTION_DELETE:
                toolbar.getMenu().clear();
                toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_delete);
                break;
            case MENU_ACTION_NONE:
                Log.d(logger, "clearing menu");
                toolbar.getMenu().clear();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_main"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/main_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24px"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentHolder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example ?

Comment: I added code, and changed the question a bit. I've discovered the same problem happens whenever the activity is created (not just on rotation). The toolbar menu is set but then disappears in the lifecycle somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my current code as posted was the line `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

This was not needed, and was in fact causing the troubling lifecycle problems stated above.